# Dynamically loop through javascript arrays

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am attempting to create a graph with up to 25 different data points in javascript. The javascript method I have created works great except for one issue - I have many different arrays and I need a solution that enables me to use a for loop to access each one. Here is my code:

```js
var dataPoints1 = [];
var dataPoints2 = [];
var dataPoints3 = [];
var dataPoints4 = [];
var dataPoints5 = [];
var dataPoints6 = [];
var dataPoints7 = [];
var dataPoints8 = [];
var dataPoints9 = [];
var dataPoints10 = [];
var dataPoints11 = [];
var dataPoints12 = [];
var dataPoints13 = [];
var dataPoints14 = [];
var dataPoints15 = [];
var dataPoints16 = [];
var dataPoints17 = [];
var dataPoints18 = [];
var dataPoints19 = [];
var dataPoints20 = [];
var dataPoints21 = [];
var dataPoints22 = [];
var dataPoints23 = [];
var dataPoints24 = [];
var dataPoints25 = [];

function addData(data) {
  var columnCount = @Html.Raw(Model.columnCount);
  var columns = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.DataPointHeaders));

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (var k = 1; k < columnCount; k++) {
      dataPoints[i].push({
        x: i,
        y: parseFloat(data[i].columns[k])
      });
    }
  }
  chart.render();
}
```

The above code works great until the second for loop, which I attempt to say dataPoints[i].push

I understand it is not possible to use the i index variable to access these datapoints, due to the fact that they are separate array variables in javascript.

My issue is that it is necessary to keep each set of dataPoints separate from each other, but I still would prefer to loop over and "create" each dataPoints set.

Is there a way to achieve this using my current code, and if not, could I use a 2 dimensional array instead and how could I implement that?

Each dataPoint set needs to be able to be accessed separately obviously.

I am not including the code where I actually use the dataPoints due to length issues, but again, it is necessary that they are separate from one another.

Comment: why not take an array for all data points?

Comment: You mention having separate arrays is `necessary` but I'm sure it actually isn't. For example instead of referring to `dataPoints2` in your code, you could refer to `dataPoints[2]` etc...

Comment: Also note that outputting `@Html.Raw()` in to your JS isn't good practice. Keep the JS and the View separated. Output the `Model.columnCount` in to your view in a data attribute (for example) and read that value from the DOM in your separate .js file.

Comment: @NinaScholz For that to happen I would need a 2 dimensional array. I read that two dimensional arrays are not supported in JS

Comment: @EliHellmer you can create multi-dimensional arrays in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Although using one single array is best practice, you can refer to variables in a dynamic way by referencing them on the `windows` object.

This is not best practice but it will solve the immediate problem instead of using best practice of a single array.

```
window["dataPoints" + i].push({
  x: i,
  y: parseFloat(data[i].columns[k])
});
```

Below is an example of a multi-dimensional array with objects, and it also includes one dynamic key and value for example purposes.

```js
var dataPoints = new Array();
dataPoints[0] = {"aa" : "1","b" : "1"};
dataPoints[1] = {"aa" : "2","b" : "3"};
dataPoints[2] = {"aa" : "3","b" : "33"};
dataPoints[3] = {"aa" : "4","b" : "43"};
dataPoints[4] = {};
dataPoints[4]["test"] = "xxx";

console.log(dataPoints);
```

Comment: Cool idea. But when using this method I get the following error "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined at Object.addData"

Comment: @EliHellmer that could be a problem with the counter itself. Your first array ends with a `1` (dataPoints1) but your loop starts at `0` which means the first iteration would cause an error since `dataPoints0` doesn't exist.